# WinDbg: range limit for dd <address> L <length>

Tags: windbg

WinDbg has a range limit applied for the d-command series. According to the documentation, the limit is at 256 MB. This limit can be bypassed using the L? syntax.

> L? Size (with a question mark) means the same as LSize, except that L?
>   Size removes the debugger's automatic range limit. Typically, there is
>   a range limit of 256 MB, because larger ranges are typographic errors.
>   If you want to specify a range that is larger than 256 MB, you must
>   use the L? Size syntax.

However, I tried to do a 
`du 3ddabac0+8 L 0n6518040`
which is only 6.5 MB and it says
`Range error in 'du 3ddabac0+8 l 0n6518040`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real limit in WinDbg 6.3 is 512kB. Starting from 0x80001 or 0n524289 you need to use L? to bypass the limit.