# How to pass hexadecimal numbers into a WinDBG command?

Tags: python, windbg, hex

I'm pretty new to hexadecimal and Windows Debugger commands. I'm trying to write a python script in which I call the '.writemem function, providing a filename, a start address, and a number of bytes to write. Here's what I have so far:

```
cmdstr = ".writemem " + filename + " " + startAddress + " L" + size
dbgCommand(cmdstr)
```

where beginAddress is a string of the start address in hexadecimal form, and size is also a hexadecimal string. The lone 'L' is meant to indicate that I don't want to specify a range of addresses, and will instead specify a start and a size.

The few examples I've found of this command being run have all omitted the '0x' from the beginning of both strings, and I was wondering if I needed to do that. I'm a little afraid to run it and see, since writemem is a dangerous function to play around with. Any ideas how to format this hexadecimal?

Comment: To clarify, my variables are already in hex form (as strings) with the preceding '0x' and I'm wondering if I need to remove this prefix before I pass these arguments to the dbgCommand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default WinDbg treats numbers as hex, so the `0x` prefix is optional. However, I'd prefer to be more explicit and just keep the `0x`prefix.

You can try that with the `?` command:

```
0:003> ? f
Evaluate expression: 15 = 00000000`0000000f
0:003> ? 0xf
Evaluate expression: 15 = 00000000`0000000f
```

If you want to use decimal values, you can use the `0n`prefix:

```
0:003> ? 0n15
Evaluate expression: 15 = 00000000`0000000f
```

Just as a side note: be aware of [the range limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515315/windbg-range-limit-for-dd-address-l-length) and use the `L?` syntax for regions larger than 512 kB.

Answer (score 0):

See [hex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) function.  Converts int into hexadecimal.